# What Star Trek movie/show are these images of a girl missing her school shuttle taken from?

Tags: star-trek, episode-identification

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZKC0Vj3_GA) contains a few shots I can't quite place, apparently featuring a girl missing her school shuttle.

[image: Girl in red shirt and beige pants walking towards a school shuttle stop. A shuttle is hovering above it]
[image: Several students in red shirts, beige pants, walking towards the shuttle barrier. A redhead girl]
[image: First girl seen from behind, the shuttle is departing without her, and she cannot reach it because of some kind of blue-ish force field]

I'm not extremely well-versed in old *Trek*, but these images look very modern, meaning they have to come from *Discovery*, *Picard* or one of the Kelvin films. As far as I know I'm completely caught up with all of those, yet I still can't for the life of me recall having seen this scene before.

Comment: No idea, but maybe *Into Darkness*? Noel Clarke’s character has a kid. A sick kid, admittedly. It’s not Discovery or Picard. Could be a Short Trek, I haven’t seen those.

Comment: I don't think it's _Into Darkness_, because they never showed a school in my memory.

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/School_shuttle_stop

Comment: Okay, so it's actually from _Star Trek: Short Treks, "Children of Mars._

Comment: 'star trek girl missing her school shuttle' - your question made that the third hit instead of the second (SE is easy after you write the question)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This image shows a school shuttle heading for a school, or carrying kids home from school:

[image: Wider view of the school suttle stop. A shuttle is hovering over it]

It's from *"Children of Mars,"* a Short Trek ([Wikia link](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Children_of_Mars_(episode))).

Modern *Star Trek* gives a better idea of what daily life is like on Earth. The two girls, who go to the same school, are Kima, a humanoid girl, and Lil, a human girl.

The Short Trek is set just a few years earlier than *Star Trek: Picard.*

This is a [good review](https://trekmovie.com/2020/01/10/review-star-trek-short-treks-children-of-mars/) that describes the story--just watch out for spoilers in case you haven't seen it.